# Iterator return in vector::begin()

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I don't quite get what `vector::begin()` actually returns.

Cplusplus.com tells me that `vector::begin()` returns the iterator of the vector, which means that for `vector<int> v;`, it will give 0.

However, when I debug on Visual Studio, the watch table showed me the value of the first element of `v`. Moreover, the "Type" column denoted that it was a `std::_Vector_iterator`.

As a consequence, what actually is the output of `vector::begin()`?

Comment: `std::vector::begin`() returns either `std::vector::iterator` or `std::vector::const_iterator`, depending upon whether it's called for a mutable or a constant vector. The fact that your development tools helpfully tell you what the iterator is referencing, only serves to confuse you. it also doesn't help that your C++ library's implementation uses, apparently, `typedef` aliases, so you see the underlying types.

Comment: It returns an iterator. `0` is not an iterator.

Comment: Please format your question properly, angle brackets gets eaten up as html tags.

Comment: _"... it will give 0"__ No it will return an iterator with the value `v.end();`  For an empty `std::vector<int> v;` you will always find that `v.begin() == v.end()`

Comment: `v.begin()` for empty `vector<int> v` returns `v.end()`, not 0.

Comment: And for a non-empty vector `begin` returns an iterator to the element ad index `0`, which perhaps is the source of your confusion? Think of iterators not as indexes (they aren't) but more like pointers to elements (they aren't that either, but it's closer and iterators emulates the interface of pointers).

Comment: anyway, not relating to the topic, I wonder why I got a down grade?

Comment: Side note: cplusplus.com is rather infamous for occasional inaccuracies or misleading info. cppreference.com is generally considered a better resource.

Comment: To add helpful info, an iterator is much like a pointer. If you dereference an iterator you will get the value of the iterator. There are 4 types of iterators Forward Moving, Backward Moving, Forward and Backward Moving (called bidirectional) and Random access.

Comment: Read a better reference than cplusplus.com : [std::vector::begin](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/begin)

Comment: @KeithBecker There is no iterator which only supports `--` without also supporting `++`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::vector::begin` returns an iterator. An iterator is a generalisation of a pointer — it's a type which can be used to access elements of a container. Each container provides its own iterator type. How exactly iterators are represented is an implementation detail, you as a programmer should only care about their interface (and guarantees they make about stability, validity, etc. See [suitable documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Iterator) for more info).

Different types of iterators support different operations: some can only be incremeneted (can only move forward), some can also be decremented (move backward); some need to move one step at a time, some can move by multiple elements in one go; etc.

The iterators provided by `std::vector` are random-access and contiguos, so they function almost exactly the same as pointers do.

For an empty `std::vector`, calling `begin()` will give you the exact same iterator as is returned by calling `end()`. `end()` always returns a special, *past-the-end* iterator. That iterator is not dereferenceable (it doesn't point to any element), it just serves as an indicator of the container's end.

Answer (score 1):

> Cplusplus.com tells me that `vector::begin()` returns the iterator of the vector,

That is correct.

> which means that for  `vector<int> v;`, it will give 0.

That is an incorrect conclusion from the previous statement. `std::vector<T>::begin()` returns an iterator that can be used to access the contents of the first element of the object, if it is not empty.

Given,

```
std::vector<int> v;
auto iter = v.begin();
int b = *iter; // Problem since the vector is empty.
```

and

```
std::vector<int> v{1, 3, 10};
auto iter = v.begin();
int b = *iter; // OK. b is the first element of the vector
int c = v[0];  // OK. c is also the first element of the vector.
```

Perhaps you confusion stems from the fact that the last two lines above evaluate to the same value.

However...

`std::vector<T>::iterator` is a type in the template `std::vector`. It is a `RandomAccessIterator`. You can read more about it, i.e. `RandomAccessIterator`, at [http://en.cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/RandomAccessIterator).